# I am facing the problem while running command mongo as I had downloaded zip file of mongodb for windows X64

Tags: mongodb

Error : The command mongod was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type: ".\mongod". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by re downloading the zip file of mongodb which was not actually the latest version of mongodb.

This error is coming because the bin folder does not contains some required .exe files that are needed for starting the server